# compare 2 variables in jelly script

Tags: xml, jenkins, jelly, jenkins-email-ext, email-publisher

```html
<j:set var="maxEachOSTime" value="0" />
<j:if test="${xmlval &gt; maxEachOSTime}">
    ${xmlval} &gt; ${ maxEachOSTime}
    <j:set var="maxEachOSTime" value="${xmlval}"/>
    <j:set var="finalTotalDuration" value="${total_duration}"/>
</j:if>
```

> if ${xmlval} is compared with a number ( 1, 200, etc) it works. But
> when compared with ${eachMaxOSTime}   it doesnt work. (condition is
> always working as true)  .intValue() also didnt help. What is the
> solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what that finally helped me in my specific use case.

xmlval is variable which has integer value by reading from xml file

maxEachOSTime var was set as string by default via <j:set>

Converted that into float and used its intValue()

Earlier intValue() was not working as String didnt have attribute intValue, hence the if condition was getting skipped.

This can be improvised by working directly into integers

```
<j:new className="java.lang.Float" var="tempFloat">
    <j:arg value="${maxEachOSTime}" type="float"/>
</j:new>
<j:set var="intThing" value="${tempFloat.intValue()}"/>
<j:if test="${xmlval &gt; intThing}">
    <j:set var="maxEachOSTime" value="${xmlval}"/>
    <j:set var="finalTotalDuration" value="${total_duration}"/>
</j:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following structure is used to define a `string` variable with Jelly script:

```
<j:set var="stringVariable"  value="This is a string!"/>
<j:set var="maxEachOSTime"   value="0"/>
```

Therefore, the type of the `maxEachOSTime` variable is `string`. You are trying to equate an `integer` on the left side of the equation with a `string` using the escape character `&gt;`.

Comment: How do I declare an int value?
the variable (xmlval) is fetched by reading an xml

Eg:  duration_int="45"

basically I want to find max number after reading multiple xmls (if you have any other workable/simple solution, I'd accept that too

Comment: When applying the `toInteger()` method to the String variable, chances are the comparison will work successfully. Would you try: `<j:if test="${xmlval &gt; maxEachOSTime.toInteger()}">`

Comment: the <if> condition is getting bypassed with above change (same happens with intValue() too)

Comment: I thought that in the comparison in the above `<j:if>` block, the left side is an `int` but the right side is not working because it is a `string`. That's why I thought it might work when he applies the `toInteger()` method to the string variable on the right side of the equation.

If you want to use advanced features using variables, you need to do these operations in the **pipeline**. The keyword you should search for is `"Jenkins Pipeline: How To Define a Variable"`.

Comment: I was avoiding to read multiple xml files in jenkins pipeline. But if we see no other option, I will try that out, thanks

Comment: It worked from jelly itself, your above comments helped me to google for correct context!!

Comment: I've never worked with Jelly before. I just searched to help you.